# how to add and remove five text field again and again on add and delete button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add five text field by add button click from array and delete newly added text field by delete button click. when i click on add button five text field added again and again when i click on add button it work properly. But when i click on delete button only newly added five text field deleted not deleted again and again when i click on delete button.
this is my code

```
enter code
```

-(void)CreateTextField   // create 5 text field on button click again and again when click
    {
    NSLog(@"%d",i);

```
i=i+1;
NSArray *array;
array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Degree",@"Branch",@"Passing Year",@"Grade/%",@"Institute", nil];  /* these are Five text field name
textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int k = 0 ; k< [array count]; k++)
{
}
-(void)DeleteTextField       // delete last newly add added text field by delete button click but deleted only once not again and again deleted by click on it
{


NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[textFieldArray count]);

int var = [textFieldArray count] - 5;
int test = [textFieldArray count];

for(int p = test;p>var;p--)
{
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
   [[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:p-1] removeFromSuperview];  /* code to remove newly added text field by delete button click
   [textFieldArray removeObjectAtIndex:p-1];
} here
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you only posted code, without any description, I can only assume you require the code for the empty for loop in the `CreateTextFields`.

Try this:

```
float textFieldHeight = 42;
float spacing = 8;
float width = 300;

for(int k = 0; k < [array count]; k++)
{
     UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, i*(textFieldHeight + spacing), width, textFieldHeight)];
     // ... other things you'd like to do with the textField
     [textFieldArray addObject:textField];
}
```

Of course you need to set your own dimensions, instead of the hard coded ones, specified in my sample. This should work, provided that is what you are looking  for, of course. Good luck!!